# How bad is having multiple HashMaps created?

Tags: java, hashmap

I am basically just wondering how much memory making HashMaps uses.

Is it better to make a HashMap of type `Object` and cast when getting? Or is it ok to make many HashMaps for the different types I want to store?

Example:

```
HashMap<Integer,Type1> map1;
HashMap<Integer,Type2> map2;
HashMap<Integer,Type3> map3;
```

vs

```
HashMap<Integer, Object> map;
// And getting it by
(Type1)map.get(Integer); //or (Type2), etc
```

Comment: Please post some code, I suspect you are confusing between creating multiple `HashMaps` and creating multiple references to a single `HashMap`, going by your explanation of casting

Comment: No I am not confusing this. Will update with code though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid creating a `HashMap` with a value of object.  Take advantage of the generic features of `HashMap` to avoid having casts all over the place in your code.  Regarding memory, I would use the `HashMap` if appropriate an worry about memory when it becomes and issue, addressing it once it rears its head.  Most normal initializations of `HashMap` shouldn't create memory issues.

Comment: But it's definitely going to consume more memory if he/she uses separate hashmaps for each type. That's the essence of the question.

Comment: @Pointy I agree more maps = more memory, but the OP doesn't provide any information about the amount of maps they are creating, if its just a few maps, why trouble yourself with the casting?

Comment: Yes that's completely true. Premature optimization == bad. However, having multiple maps means that there must surrounding code to decide which map to use if the context really does involve a heterogeneity of different key/value types.  It's really a question of what's more messy.

Answer (score 1):

It matters how you're going to use these HashMaps.  If you're storing values of multiple types and using one set of keys, then you should use one HashMap.  If you're storing values of multiple types and using a different set of keys for each type, you should use multiple maps.

The difference in memory cost between 100 HashMaps and 1 is pretty small.  The biggest thing you'll notice is that if you have lots of tiny HashMaps (like, thousands of maps with only 2 or 3 values in each map), then you'll waste a lot of space because the default constructor expects ~16 values.  To fix this, just initialize your HashMaps with the expected size:

```
HashMap<Foo> fooMap = new HashMap<Foo>(5);
```

Comment: I like your explanation of the constructor parameter. I didn't know about that

Comment: Even if you specify a smaller parm, the minimum size of the array created for the hashmap will be the minimum size of an array of references.  This is probably in the neighborhood of 4, for a 64-bit implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter at runtime what the "type" of the hashmap is, as the JVM doesn't even know about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's going to be something of a wash.  With multiple maps you have multiple objects and multiple hashtables (which have some minimum "overhead"), but beyond a certain size that initial cost is "buried", and the multiple tables would hash ever so slightly faster.

There is, however, no difference in the overhead of casts, since the casts are there when you use generics, just hidden